# How do I pass a List/Set/Array to Apache QueryRunner as parameter value?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there any way to perform the following query:

```
select * from table where field in (?)
```

and pass a list/set/array as a value for `?` placeholder.

I'm using QueryRunner from the Apache db-commons library.

Comment: For those that aren't familiar, please show the code so we know the API available.

Comment: I believe you can use ('value1', 'value2'), but those would come before the "in", and `field` would come after. Could be wrong on the otdering.

Comment: I have a big select query (~35 lines), my idea is to store the query in the resource file near the class file, let it be `SearchController.java` and `SearchController.findClientByIp.sql`. This big query should find client by ip, or a list of ip addresses. I wouldn't like to construct query each time, i.e. if I have 2 ip addresses as input, then rewrite query as `where ip in (?,?)`. This is my controller code snippet http://pastebin.com/JV8KhxJG and sql code snippet http://pastebin.com/tjVjBaZB

Comment: I had this same problem once and found that it is not possible with the QueryRunner class.  You will have to write some custom code for this.

Answer (score 3):

Sure there is, use [createArrayOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createArrayOf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
final List<Integer> id = new ArrayList<>();
id.add(12);
id.add(15);

final Array toDelete = connection.createArrayOf("int", id.toArray());

queryRunner.query(
    connection,
    "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY(?)",
    resultSetHandler,
    toDelete
);
```

(example is using PostgreSQL but should also work for others)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work with SQLite. `commons-dbutils` version `1.7`

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of natively supported Array types. For example `String[]`. QueryRunner takes variable arguments and this is will get confused with the array type, so you would need to cast it to Object.

```
final int[] ids = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

queryRunner.query(
    connection,
    "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ANY(?)",
    resultSetHandler,
    (Object) ids
);
```

Supported primitive arrays in PostgreSQL:

```
static {
  ARRAY_CLASS_TO_SUPPORT.put(long[].class, LONG_ARRAY);
  ARRAY_CLASS_TO_SUPPORT.put(int[].class, INT_ARRAY);
  ARRAY_CLASS_TO_SUPPORT.put(short[].class, SHORT_ARRAY);
  ARRAY_CLASS_TO_SUPPORT.put(double[].class, DOUBLE_ARRAY);
  ARRAY_CLASS_TO_SUPPORT.put(float[].class, FLOAT_ARRAY);
  ARRAY_CLASS_TO_SUPPORT.put(boolean[].class, BOOLEAN_ARRAY);
  ARRAY_CLASS_TO_SUPPORT.put(String[].class, STRING_ARRAY);
}
```

[PrimitiveArraySupport.java](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.5.jre6/source-code/org/postgresql/jdbc/PrimitiveArraySupport.java)